# New to RHEL; Coming from Fedora; Different repo managers?

Tags: rhel8, dnf

I'm coming from fedora. Just testing the waters in RHEL 8.2

None of my standard dnf packages are available. For instance:

```sh
$ sudo dnf install powerline powerline-fonts
[sudo] password for adamhanna: 
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:09:50 ago on Tue 16 Jun 2020 09:38:48 PM PDT.
No match for argument: powerline
No match for argument: powerline-fonts
Error: Unable to find a match: powerline powerline-fonts
```

To be clear, this isn't the only package giving me problems.

Sorry for the basic question, but I've searched and can't find my answer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RHEL itself doesn't ship a large number of packages; only those they can provide professional support for.

A large number of additional packages you may be looking for are in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository, which many RHEL and CentOS users add as it contains most of the long tail of packages people are going to be looking for. While EPEL packages are almost always maintained by the same Red Hat employees and community members who maintain the corresponding Fedora packages, Red Hat will not provide support for them under your support agreement.

With respect to the specific packages you named, I don't believe they are (yet) packaged for EPEL. You can contact the [Fedora package maintainer](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/powerline/) and [ask for it to be packaged](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Getting_a_Fedora_package_in_EPEL).

Comment: Thank you so much! https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: @adam-m-hanna And apparently the link to find the package maintainer is not working due to being under (a very lengthy) maintenance, and may not be back for a few weeks. I can tell you from other means not easily hyperlinked that the package maintainer is asn (at redhat dot com).